Mel Spectrogram in R
I am new to acoustic data analysis and am working with R. I installed seewave, av, phonTools, tuneR, and torchaudio. I can plot spectra using functions such as spectro and spectrogram. I was able to find the mel and melfilterbank functions.
Is there a way to directly obtain a Mel spectrogram in R from a .wav file or its extracted signal?

To you comment below, see tuneR::melfcc and if doing a lot of this analysis Sueur, J.,  You also might want to add soundgen to your audio processing stack. Docs there are thoughtful and complement Sueur.

You can read your .wav file in with readWave from the "tuneR" package, and plot the spectrogram with spectro from the "seewave" package:
library(tuneR)
library(seewave)

download.file("https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/taunt.wav", "taunt.wav")

my_wav <- readWave("taunt.wav")
spectro(my_wav, collevels = seq(-100, -15, 5))



Thanks @Allan Cameron. Is spectro a Mel Spectrogram or just a regular spectrogram?

For mel, using just tuneR, as above:
library(tuneR)
download.file("https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/taunt.wav", "taunt.wav")
my_wav <- readWave("taunt.wav")
str(taunt_wav)
Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
  ..@ left     : int [1:91240] 117 118 118 120 122 126 131 135 136 135 ...
  ..@ right    : num(0) 
  ..@ stereo   : logi FALSE
  ..@ samp.rate: int 22257
  ..@ bit      : int 8
  ..@ pcm      : logi TRUE
#?melfcc Usage:
#  melfcc(samples, sr = samples@samp.rate, wintime = 0.025, 
#         hoptime = 0.01, numcep = 12, lifterexp = 0.6, htklifter = FALSE,
#         sumpower = TRUE, preemph = 0.97, dither = FALSE,
#         minfreq = 0, maxfreq = sr/2, nbands = 40, bwidth = 1, 
#         dcttype = c("t2", "t1", "t3", "t4"), 
#         fbtype = c("mel", "htkmel", "fcmel", "bark"), usecmp = FALSE, 
#         modelorder = NULL, spec_out = FALSE, frames_in_rows = TRUE)

# some helpers
wl <- 512
ncep <- 13
f <- taunt_wav@samp.rate

# common setting suggested by Sueur
taunt_mel <- melfcc(taunt_wav, sr = f, wintime = wl/f, hoptime = wl/f,
numcep = ncep, nbands = ncep*2, fbtype = "htkmel", dcttype = "t3",
htklifter = TRUE, lifterexp = ncep -1, frames_in_rows = FALSE, spec_out = TRUE)

# and plotting
image(t(taunt_mel$cepstra), col = hcl.colors(13), axes = FALSE, xlab = 'Time (s)', ylab = 'MFCC #')
at <- seq(0, 1, length=5)
time <- round(seq(0, 91240/22257, length = 5))
axis(side = 1, at = at, labels = time)
axis(side =2, at=0:12/12, labels=1:13, )
abline(h=(0:12/12) + 1/(12*2), col = 'lightgray')
abline(v=(0:73/73) +1/(73*2), col = 'lightgray')
box()


